# jQuery change select list value based on two option values

Tags: jquery

I have two select lists and need to change the value of one based on their current state so:

Select list 1:

```
Option A (All)
Option B (12)
Option C (13)
```

Select list 2:

```
Option 1 (All)
Option 2 (14)
Option 3 (15)
Option 4 (16)
```

If select list 1 = Option C && select list 2 = Option 2 then change select list 1 to Option A.

I have the following code:

```
$('#edit-lines, #edit-trading-options').change(function () {
  if ($('#edit-lines').val().indexOf(13) && $('#edit-trading-options').val().indexOf(14) > -1) $('#edit-trading-options').val('All');
});
```

But something's not right. The second select stays at 'All' all the time.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: instead of .val().indexOf(13), you should use .val() == 13.

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your situation.?

Comment: Or if you must use `.indexOf`, you need to use `!= -1`, like you did for the second test.

Comment: Is this a multi-select?

Answer (score 2):

If just those 2 specific options, then do this:

```
$('#edit-lines, #edit-trading-options').change(function () {
  if ($('#edit-lines').val() == 13 && $('#edit-trading-options').val() == 14)
     $('#edit-trading-options').val('All');
});
```

Comment: Thanks David. Just tried in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mj9L7/1/ and works great. I also have an AJAX layer that auto submits when there is a state change to either select list. Using the code in dev, it doesn't work until I refresh the page. I'm assuming this is related? Any ideas how I could prevent this?

Comment: So glad that worked for you.  Not sure I understand your follow-up question.  Could you provide more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `#edit-lines` is the **first** select, so why do you change the value of the second one?
Also, the first condition in the `if` statement is wrong. It would always return TRUE, since you're comparing strings with numbers (number `13` passed as the `indexOf`'s argument).
You don't need to use `.indexOf()` method. Simply compare the values.

Here's the example:

```
$('#edit-lines, #edit-trading-options').change(function () {
    if ($('#edit-lines').val() == 13 && $('#edit-trading-options').val() == 14)
        $('#edit-lines').val('All');
});
```